# 'Let me take you past the satellite' meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions, lyrics

I was listening to Ellie Goulding's song 'Love me like you do' and came across a phrase/ expression **let me take you past the satellite**. I don't know what it means. I searched for similar phrases like *take someone past something* and some others but there's nothing that could answer my question.

Does anyone know what it means?

Here are the lyrics of the song:

> [...]
> You're the fear, I don't care
> Cause I've never been so high
> Follow me through the dark
>
> **Let me take you past the satellites**
>
> You can see the world you brought to life, to life.
>
> So love me like you do, la-la-love me like you do
> [...]

Comment: "I will take you flying through the sky" is a fairly common thing to hear in love songs; this is a variation of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lyric you quote says "past the satellites", with the plural. It probably refers to man-made earth satellites. So, in context, "...I've never been so high... follow me... to an altitude higher than that of the satellites".

Answer (score -1):

The phrase means "let me take you to beyond the planet in outer space".

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! Please explain why your answer is correct; answers without explanation don't teach the patterns of English well.